# .htaccess: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I know this has been answered before, but .htaccess files are quite personal in their design and I've found it difficult to apply the fixes found in other posts to my .htaccess file.  This .htaccess it in the root of the webdir and causes this error:

```
"[error] [client 1.1.1.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace".
```

If someone could please point out the flaw in my .htaccess, I would be so grateful!  Thank you!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)\.  (gif|jpeg|jpg|png|css|js|pdf|doc|xml|ico|html|php|json|swf|mp3|ogg|wav)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(service)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/                  [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^[^/.]*/(.*)    app/$1     [L]
```

Comment: [Please use `FallbackResource` for basic fancy URL implementations](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource). Using `mod_rewrite` for this is like shooting a cannon at a rubber boat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea what you;re trying to do but it looks like you need a:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !app/
```

right before:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/.]*/(.*)    app/$1     [L]
```